# fatal error: gstdint.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, gdb, kernel, qemu

I gonna debugging kernel with QEMU to GDB.
I had commanded such as "make && sudo make install" on GDB though, Error have shown up.

Error Message:

```
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/work/Kernel/linux-kernel/qemu/binutils-gdb/gdb'
g++ -std=gnu++11 -g -02 -I. -I. -I./common -I./config -DLOCALEDIR=""/usr/local/share/locale"" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I./../include/opcode -I./../opcodes/.. -I./../readline/.. -I./../zlib -I../bfd -I./../bfd -I./../include -I../libdecnumber -I./../libdecnumber -I./gnulib/import -Ibuild-gunlib/import -DTUI=1 -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused -Wunused-value -Wunused-function -Wno-switch -Wno-char-subscripts -Wempty-body -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-write-strings -Wno-narrowing -Wformat-nonliteral -c -o dfp.o -MT dfp.o -MMD -MP -MF .deps/dfp.Tpo dfp.c
In file included from ../libdecnumber/decNumber.h:37:0,
                 from ../libdecnumber/dpd/decimal128.h:58,
                 from dfp.c:29:
../libdecnumber/decContext.h:54:61: fatal error: gstdint.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:1872: recipe for target 'dfp.o' failed
make: *** [dfp.o] Error 1enter code here
```

What should I do? Please, help me.
Thank you.

Comment: What about configure? (see https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2007-04/msg00759.html)

Comment: @dbrank0  I used  `./congifure --disable-werror`. Sorry, English isn't my first language. (Also I'm not used to working in linux.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `configure` in the `libdecnumber` before building gdb.